# Barcode scanner with keyboardhook not giving proper result when window is focused

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I am trying to integrate a barcode scanner in WPF application, whenever i scan a code when the main window is out of focus i get the correct result. but if window is focused the scanned data from keyboard hook is not proper. Please someone help me with this

```
   public class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        #region Private Members
        private string PrefixString { get; set; }
        System.Timers.Timer g_MagneticReader;
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardProc;
        private IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

        const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        private IList<Keys> MagneticStrip { get; set; }

        public delegate void sendDataToWebORT(DeviceData value);
        public event sendDataToWebORT notifyScannedData;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public KeyboardHook(string prefixString)
        {
            if (prefixString.Contains('~'))
            {
                string[] getPrefixString = prefixString.Split('~');
                PrefixString = getPrefixString[1];

            }
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.keyboardProc = HookCallback;
                hookId = SetHook(this.keyboardProc);
                g_MagneticReader = new System.Timers.Timer();
                g_MagneticReader.Elapsed += G_MagneticReader_Elapsed;
                g_MagneticReader.Interval = 200;
                MagneticStrip = new List<Keys>();
            });


        }
        #endregion

        #region Dll's
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
                                                   LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
                                                    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ToAscii(uint uVirtKey, uint uScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out] StringBuilder lpChar, uint uFlags);
        #endregion

        
        #region Functions
        private void G_MagneticReader_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            g_MagneticReader.Stop();
            //var enteredtext = GetStringFromKeys(MagneticStrip);
            var enteredtext = finalOutput.ToString();

            if (null != notifyScannedData)
            {
                //enteredtext.Clear();
                //enteredtext.Append("sqa4170832612");
                Logger.Default.LogInfo("Scanning Started - Start" + enteredtext.ToString(), nameof(KeyboardHook));
                //Logger.Info("Prefix string is - " + _PrefixString);
                //Logger.Info("Before removing prefix 1- " + enteredtext.ToString());
                //Logger.Info("_IsQRKeyboard- " + _IsQRKeyboard.ToString());
                string valueCheck = enteredtext.ToString();
                //if (enteredtext.Length > 12 && !_IsQRKeyboard)
                //{
                //    DeviceData obj = new DeviceData();
                //    if (enteredtext.ToString().StartsWith("5") && enteredtext.ToString().EndsWith("/"))
                //    {

                //        obj.Data = enteredtext.ToString().ToUpper().Substring(1, enteredtext.ToString().Length - 2);
                //        obj.device = DevicesSupported.mcr;
                //        obj.messageType = DeviceMessage.MagneticData;
                //    }
                //    else if (enteredtext.ToString().StartsWith("%") && enteredtext.ToString().EndsWith("?"))
                //    {

                //        obj.Data = enteredtext.ToString().ToUpper().Substring(1, enteredtext.ToString().Length - 2);
                //        obj.device = DevicesSupported.mcr;
                //        obj.messageType = DeviceMessage.MagneticData;
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        obj.Data = enteredtext.ToString().ToUpper();
                //        obj.device = DevicesSupported.mcr;
                //        obj.messageType = DeviceMessage.MagneticData;
                //    }
                //    KeyCombinationPressed.Invoke(obj);
                //}
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PrefixString) && valueCheck.ToLower().Contains(PrefixString.ToLower()))
                {
                    Logger.Default.LogInfo("Before removing prefix - " + enteredtext.ToString(), nameof(KeyboardHook));
                    enteredtext = enteredtext.Replace(PrefixString.ToLower(), "");
                    Logger.Default.LogInfo("After removing prefix -  " + enteredtext.ToString(), nameof(KeyboardHook));
                    DeviceData obj = new DeviceData();
                    obj.data = enteredtext.ToString();
                    notifyScannedData.Invoke(obj);
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    Logger.Default.LogInfo("Before removing prefix - " + enteredtext.ToStrinA#%
                //    g(), nameof(KeyboardHook));
                //    DeviceData obj = new DeviceData();
                //    obj.data = enteredtext.ToString();
                //    notifyScannedData.Invoke(obj);
                //}

            }
            finalOutput.Clear();
            MagneticStrip.Clear();
            //KeyCombinationPressed.Invoke(new DeviceData() { Data = "true", device = DevicesSupported.mcr, messageType = DeviceMessage.MagneticDataEnded });
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }
        StringBuilder GetStringFromKeys(IList<Keys> input)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                byte[] keyState = new byte[256];


                foreach (ushort vk in input)
                {
                    //if (vk == 13)
                    //{
                    //    break;
                    //}

                    AppendChar(output, vk, ref keyState);


                }
            });

            return output;
        }
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint dwLayout);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint MapVirtualKeyEx(uint uCode, uint uMapType, IntPtr dwhkl);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);

        private static void ClearKeyboardBuffer(uint vk, uint sc, IntPtr hkl)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(10);

            int rc;
            do
            {
                byte[] lpKeyStateNull = new Byte[255];
                rc = ToUnicodeEx(vk, sc, lpKeyStateNull, sb, sb.Capacity, 0, hkl);
            } while (rc < 0);
        }

       
        private static uint lastVKCode = 0;
        private static uint lastScanCode = 0;
        private static byte[] lastKeyState = new byte[255];
        private static bool lastIsDead = false;
        private object lockobj = new object();
        MetroWindow MainWindow;
        public void GetMainWindowInstance(MetroWindow mainWindow)
        {
            MainWindow = mainWindow;
        }
        private void AppendChar(StringBuilder output, uint vKey, ref byte[] keyState)
        {
            lock (lockobj)
            { 
                Keyboard.ClearFocus();
                MainWindow.Focusable = false;
                MainWindow.Topmost = false;
                MainWindow.IsEnabled = true;
             

                //App.Current.MainWindow.IsActive = false;
                g_MagneticReader.Stop();
                bool bKeyStateStatus;
                bool isDead = false;
                byte[] bKeyState = new byte[255];
                System.Text.StringBuilder sbString = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);
                // Gets the current windows window handle, threadID, processID

                //dummyWindow.Topmost = false;

                IntPtr windowHandle =
            new WindowInteropHelper(App.DummyWindow).Handle;
                IntPtr currentHWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
                uint currentProcessID;
                uint currentWindowThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(currentHWnd, out currentProcessID);
                // This programs Thread ID
                uint thisProgramThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
                if (AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, true))
                {
                    // Current state of the modifiers in keyboard
                    bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(keyState);

                    // Detach
                    AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, false);
                    Logger.Default.LogInfo($"Execute 1 {bKeyStateStatus}", nameof(KeyboardHook));
                }
                else
                {


                    // Detach
                    //AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, false);
                    //Logger.Default.LogInfo($"Execute 1 {bKeyStateStatus}", nameof(KeyboardHook));

                    // Could not attach, perhaps it is this process?
                    bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(keyState);
                    //AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, false);
                    Logger.Default.LogInfo($"Execute 2 {bKeyStateStatus}", nameof(KeyboardHook));
                }
                if (!bKeyStateStatus)
                    return;

                // Gets the layout of keyboard
                IntPtr HKL = GetKeyboardLayout(currentWindowThreadID);
                uint lScanCode = MapVirtualKeyEx(vKey, 0, HKL);

                //if (!isKeyDown)
                //    return ;
                //int n = ToAscii(vKey, 0, bKeyState, sbString, 0);
                int relevantKeyCountInBuffer = ToUnicodeEx(vKey, lScanCode, keyState, sbString, sbString.Capacity, (uint)0, HKL);

                string ret = "";
                switch (relevantKeyCountInBuffer)
                {
                    // Dead keys (^,`...)
                    case -1:
                        isDead = true;

                        // We must clear the buffer because ToUnicodeEx messed it up, see below.
                        ClearKeyboardBuffer(vKey, lScanCode, HKL);
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        break;

                    // Single character in buffer
                    case 1:

                        ret = sbString[0].ToString();
                        if ((System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers & System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Shift) == System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Shift)
                        {
                            ret = ret.ToUpper();
                        }
                        Logger.Default.LogInfo($"scanned string {ret}", nameof(KeyboardHook));
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    ret = ret.ToLower();
                        //}
                        output.Append(ret);
                        break;


                    // Two or more (only two of them is relevant)
                    case 2:
                    default:
                        ret = sbString.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                        break;
                }
                if (lastVKCode != 0 && lastIsDead)
                {
                    System.Text.StringBuilder sbTemp = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);
                    ToUnicodeEx(lastVKCode, lastScanCode, lastKeyState, sbTemp, sbTemp.Capacity, (uint)0, HKL);
                    lastVKCode = 0;


                }

                lastScanCode = lScanCode;
                lastVKCode = vKey;
                lastIsDead = isDead;
                lastKeyState = (byte[])keyState.Clone();
                g_MagneticReader.Start();
                //MainWindow.Focusable = true;
                //dummyWindow.Close();
            }
          














            //if (MapVirtualKey(vKey, 2) == 0)
            //{
            //    keyState[vKey] = 0x80;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    StringBuilder chr = new StringBuilder(2);
            //    int n = ToAscii(vKey, 0, keyState, chr, 0);

            //    if (n > 0)
            //        output.Append(chr.ToString(0, n));

            //    keyState = new byte[256];
            //}
        }
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int ToUnicode(
    uint virtualKey, uint scanCode, byte[] keyStates,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)][Out] char[] chars,
    int charMaxCount, uint flags);

        private IntPtr HookCallback(
         int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            try
            {
                if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN))
                //IGNORE Down events and take UP events
                //if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP))
                {
                    //g_MagneticReader.Stop();
                    int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                    string keyPressed = string.Empty;
                    bool IsKeyReqired = false;
                    if (vkCode == (int)Keys.LShiftKey)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "LS";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.RShiftKey)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "RS";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.ShiftKey)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "SK";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.Shift)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "S";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.CapsLock)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "CP";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.RControlKey)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "RCK";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.LControlKey)
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + "LCK";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else if (vkCode == (int)Keys.Space)
                    {
                        keyPressed = " ";
                        IsKeyReqired = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        keyPressed = (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) ? "Down " : "UP " + ((Keys)vkCode).ToString();
                    }

                    //// 
                    //if (MagneticStrip.Count == 0)
                    //{
                    //    //if (KeyCombinationPressed != null) new Thread(() => {
                    //    //    //KeyCombinationPressed.Invoke(new DeviceData() { Data = "true", device = DevicesSupported.mcr, messageType = DeviceMessage.MagneticDataStarted });
                    //    //}).Start();
                    //}
                    if (IsKeyReqired || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
                    {
                        MagneticStrip.Add((Keys)vkCode);
                    }

                    //g_MagneticReader.Start();
                    Logger.Default.LogInfo("sending data" + (uint)vkCode, nameof(KeyboardHook));

                    byte[] keyState = new byte[256];
                    AppendChar(finalOutput, (uint)vkCode, ref keyState);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
        private StringBuilder finalOutput = new StringBuilder();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                uint thisProgramThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
                IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                                    hInstance, 0);
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

When window is not focused - "L4009100Z234111399344#2023-04-11 13:15:00#111 Apfelkuchen buy one get one#232"

When window is focused - "L$)09100z23411139934432023-04-11 13;15;003111 apfelkuchen buy one get one3232"

Comment: You code has lots of IF statements and without know which IF statements are executed it is hard to determine root cause of issue.